# What is the fastest way to check whether a folder size is greater than a specific size?

Tags: python, linux, shell

What will be the fastest way to check whether a folder size is beyond a specific size say 10 MB, 1 Gb , 10 GB etc, without actually calculating the folder size. Something like quota. A Pythonic solution will be great, but standard UNIX utilities also welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize

def getsize_limited(directory, limit):
        total_size = 0
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
            for name in files:
                total_size += getsize(join(root, name))
                if total_size > limit:
                   return limit, False
        return total_size, True
```

Example:

```
size, within_limit = getsize_limited(os.getcwd(), limit=10**6)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to say it's impossible. I don't believe any filesystems cache folder sizes. Whatever you do is going to have to walk the tree in some fashion or another. Using `du` is probably the fastest method since it's all going to be happening in C.

If you know the maximum filesize expected or supported you could perhaps optimise a little by counting the enties in each folder rather than the sizes and short-cutting in the case where there aren't enough files to meet the limit.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `du -sb`, which still have to calculate folder size .eg

```
threshold=1024000 #bytes
path="/your/path"
s=$(du -sb "$path")
set -- $s
size=$1
if [ "$size" -gt $threshold ];then
    echo "size of $path greater than $threshold"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Folder size is still the total size of the folder contents.

You may try to call `du -s foldername` from python