# very quickly getting total size of folder

Tags: python, optimization, directory

I want to quickly find the total size of any folder using python.

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize, isfile, isdir, splitext
def GetFolderSize(path):
    TotalSize = 0
    for item in os.walk(path):
        for file in item[2]:
            try:
                TotalSize = TotalSize + getsize(join(item[0], file))
            except:
                print("error with file:  " + join(item[0], file))
    return TotalSize

print(float(GetFolderSize("C:\\")) /1024 /1024 /1024)
```

That's the simple script I wrote to get the total size of the folder, it took around 60 seconds (+-5 seconds). By using multiprocessing I got it down to 23 seconds on a quad core machine.

Using the Windows file explorer it takes only ~3 seconds (Right click-> properties to see for yourself). So is there a faster way of finding the total size of a folder close to the speed that windows can do it?

Windows 7, python 2.6 (Did searches but most of the time people used a very similar method to my own)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code as presented is invalid. Could you post a complete, minimal example that you've actually run?

Comment: Sorry, only had the function before, the rest of it is edited in.

Comment: related: [Calculating a directory size using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You are at a disadvantage.

Windows Explorer almost certainly uses [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx)/[`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx) to both traverse the directory structure *and* collect size information (through `lpFindFileData`) in one pass, making what is essentially a single system call per file.

Python is unfortunately not your friend in this case.  Thus,

1. `os.walk` **first calls `os.listdir`** (which internally calls `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`)

   - **any additional system calls made from this point onward can only make you slower** than Windows Explorer
2. `os.walk` **then calls `isdir`** for each file returned by `os.listdir` (which internally calls [`GetFileAttributesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946(VS.85).aspx) -- or, prior to Win2k, a `GetFileAttributes`+`FindFirstFile` combo) to redetermine whether to recurse or not
3. `os.walk` and `os.listdir` will perform **additional memory allocation**, string and array operations etc. to fill out their return value
4. you **then call `getsize`** for each file returned by `os.walk` (which **again** calls [`GetFileAttributesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946(VS.85).aspx))

That is 3x more system calls per file than Windows Explorer, plus memory allocation and manipulation overhead.

You can either use Anurag's solution, or try to call `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` directly and recursively (which should be comparable to the performance of a [`cygwin`](http://www.cygwin.com/) or other [win32 port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) `du -s some_directory`.)

Refer to [`os.py`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release26-maint/Lib/os.py) for the implementation of `os.walk`, [`posixmodule.c`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release26-maint/Modules/posixmodule.c) for the implementation of `listdir` and `win32_stat` (invoked by both `isdir` and `getsize`.)

Note that Python's **`os.walk` is suboptimal on all platforms** (Windows and *nices), up to and including Python3.1.  On both Windows and *nices `os.walk` could achieve traversal in a single pass without calling `isdir` since both `FindFirst`/`FindNext` (Windows) and `opendir`/`readdir` (*nix) already return file type via `lpFindFileData->dwFileAttributes` (Windows) and `dirent::d_type` (*nix).

Perhaps counterintuitively, on most modern configurations (e.g. Win7 and NTFS, and even some SMB implementations) `GetFileAttributesEx` is **twice** as slow as `FindFirstFile` of a single file (possibly even slower than iterating over a directory with `FindNextFile`.)

**Update:** Python 3.5 includes the new [PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.scandir) function that solves this problem by returning file attributes along with the filename. This new function is used to speed up the built-in `os.walk()` (on both Windows and Linux). You can use the [scandir module on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) to get this behavior for older Python versions, including 2.x.

Comment: The mentioned PEP page contains an example for exactly this purpose: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/#examples

Answer (score 23):

If you want same speed as explorer, why not use the windows scripting to access same functionality using pythoncom e.g.

```
import win32com.client as com

folderPath = r"D:\Software\Downloads"
fso = com.Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folder = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)
MB = 1024 * 1024.0
print("%.2f MB" % (folder.Size / MB))
```

It will work same as explorer, you can read more about Scripting runtime at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bstcxhf7(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: That works great, amazing actually. But only most of the time.
In a directory ('C:\Downloads') with a size of 37GB and 7 000 files your method get's the result almost instantaneously. The os.walk() way get's the result back in a couple of seconds (3 seconds)

But I have some problems on other directories such as C:\Windows, C:\users etc. where it says an exception occurred.

Comment: @freakazo, C:\Windows worked on my machine, what error do you get?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print  "%.2f MB"%(folder.Size/MB)
  File "C:\python26_32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 501,
in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
 0, -2146828218), None)
Press any key to continue . . .
### A couple more tests showed that it is folder.size that's giving the problem. folder.name for example works on the C:\Windows directory

Comment: This is long dead of course but I was getting the same thing on c:\users\myname and looking it up, it was permission denied. It works on anything you've created yourself but anything system-y appears a no go, even running the script as Administrator.

Answer (score 5):

I compared the performance of the Python code against a 15k directory tree containing 190k files and compared it against the `du(1)` command which presumably goes about as fast as the OS. The Python code took 3.3 seconds compared to du which took 0.8 seconds. This was on Linux.

I'm not sure there is much to squeeze out of the Python code. Note too that the first run of du took 45 seconds which was obviously before the relevant i-nodes were in the block cache; therefore this performance is heavily dependent upon how well the system is managing its store. It wouldn't surprise me if either or both:

1. os.path.getsize is sub-optimal on Windows
2. Windows caches directory contents size once calculated

Comment: It looks like it is indeed slower on windows, on windows with a 23K directory tree and 175K files it took around 60 seconds.
Using the du windows equivalent it took 6 seconds to complete. So it looks like Python is 10x slower on windows than du and 4 times slower on linux.
So yip it seems that
1. os.path.getsize/os.walk is indeed sub-optimal on windows
2. Windows does seem to cache directory contents size
3. Windows still is just slower than linux