# Measure directory size with Python

Tags: python, scandir

I am new to Python and I need to get the size from a directory with more than 500k files. I found some code on the internet which should be really fast. Somehow it doesnt work and I dont know why.
The current output is only 'Test' so it doesnt even enter the function.

```
import time
import os

start_time = time.time()
print('Test')
def getSize(path):
    print('Test2')
    total = 0
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
            total += getSize(entry.path)
        else:
            total += entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size
    return total

    print (float(getSize('U:\Java'))/1024/1024/1024)
    print("--- %s Sekunden ---" % round(time.time() - start_time, 2))
```

Additional question: Is there an even faster way to search such big directories with python or other languages?

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python

Comment: hm, do you actually call the function? like `getSize('path/to/filder')` as a last line.

Comment: I already tried that one. I also tried this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485804/7862001the second one is faster than the method with os.walk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two last lines in your program, where you call the function, are indented and therefore considered a part of the function and will not execute. **Simply dedent them.**