# Hi, I've been trying to do a retrieval in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to do a retrieval in python

Comment: You don't have access to the `/tmp/` directory (odd). Try running Python with `sudo`.

Comment: @Blender: the script has access to `/tmp` otherwise there would be no `download_file(item)` in the traceback. It would fail sooner.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: What do you mean? The traceback points to the first line that accesses `/tmp/`.

Comment: @Blender: note: `23` line is *before* `13` (recursive call)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Oh, I completely missed that recursive call (facepalm)

Comment: I figured out that I have no access to Footemp as it is owned by another user. So i had to create Attretrieve instead of Footemp and own that myself. Apparently, it works for the other user but still doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: Also, the idea is to read from the list of file name, and retrieve each file into a target directory. I am not sure how much disk space the documents will take up; so we might want to modify the program to retrieve the files just to check the size, but not to store them.

Answer (score 2):

- the second argument to `urlretrieve()` is a filename not a directory.
- you're ignoring `docid` argument
- you probably don't want to call `download_file()` recursively
- `` `folder_size` `` (with backtick) is a syntax error

Here's a script that downloads documents specified in `/tmp/docids` to `/tmp/Footemp` directory (it must exist):

```
outdir = "/tmp/Footemp"
with open("/tmp/docids") as f:
     for line in f:
         docid = line.strip()
         if not docid: continue # skip empty lines
         name = urllib.parse.quote_plus(docid)
         url = "http://foo.com/doc/" + name
         path = os.path.join(outdir, name)
         name, info = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path)
         print(info)
```

See 
[Calculating a directory size using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392413)

Comment: +1 from me. I was just writing up a similar answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks to be correct, so it is likely a permissions error.  Try saving to a file in a directory that you know you have write access to.