# os.path.getsize Returns Incorrect Value?

Tags: python, file, directory, size

```
def size_of_dir(dirname):
    print("Size of directory: ")
    print(os.path.getsize(dirname))
```

is the code in question. dirname is a directory with **130** files of about **1kb** each. When I call this function, it returns **4624**, which is **NOT** the size of the directory...why is this?

Comment: Joe, it looks to me as if you have two answers that completely answer your question. You should accept one of them, or clarify your question if you think there's something important they haven't dealt with.

Comment: 4624 (4096 in my case) is the folder size.  I believe this is the file system minimum allocation.
The sum of contents is:  `sum(os.path.getsize('/'.join([root,file])) for root, _, files in os.walk(dirname) for file in files if file)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This value (4624B) represents the size of the *file* that *describes* that directory. Directories are described as inodes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) that hold information about the files and directories it contains.

To get the number of files/subdirectories inside that path, use:

```
len(os.listdir(dirname))
```

To get the total amount of data, you could use the code [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python), that is (as @linker posted)

```
 sum([os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]).
```

Comment: You wrote `os.path.listdir` the first time, but probably meant `os.listdir` (as you wrote the second time)..?

Comment: Note this would not get total amount of data if the directory contains sub-directories. It only works reliably on a flat directory hierarchy.

Comment: This is not accurate for all types of filesystem. `os.path.getsize` returns the value of the `st_size` field in the `stat` result, which [means different things on different file systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252311/); for example, apparently it's the number of directory entries on a ZFS file system.

Comment: Be aware that `os.path.getsize` returns the *allocated* size, while the file may actually consume much less, the *actual* size. To compute the *actual* size you'd use `os.stat(file_path).st_blocks * 512`.

Example: A VM image is allowed to grow up to 128GB, but is only using 16GB, then the allocated size will be 128GB, but the actual size used on disk will be 16GB, which means that you *can* copy that image to a 32GB USB stick to transfer it to another machine. If you copy files from one place to another, you copy *actual* size of bytes, not *allocated* size of bytes.

Answer (score 7):

Using `os.path.getsize()` will only get you the size of the directory, **NOT** of its content. So if you call `getsize()` on any directory you will always get the same size since they are all represented the same way. On contrary, if you call it on a file, it will return the actual file size.

If you want the content you will need to do it recursively, like below:

```
sum([os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)])
```

Answer (score 2):

The first answer brought me this:

```py
>>> sum([os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)])
1708
```

This is also not correct for me :( (I did check my cwd)

The code below brought me a closer result

```py
total_size = 0
for folders, subfolders, files in os.walk(dirname):
    for file in files:
        total_size += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(folders, file))
print(total_size)
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
import os

def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python Program"
    #filesize = 0
    with open(filename, 'w') as new_file:
        new_file.write(comments)
        cwd=os.getcwd()
        fpath = os.path.abspath(filename)
        filesize=os.path.getsize(fpath)
    return(filesize)

print(create_python_script('newprogram.py'))
```

it should 31 bytes but the result is getting as "0"

Comment: Hi, when you _answer_ a question, it is nice to be clear. So some code formatting ( see [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) )  would be nice, along with some explanation ; besides, there already are some good answers to that, so ideally yours shall provide a helpful alternative. At this stage, it seems to have neither of the above.