# In Python, what is the difference between os.path.getsize(directory) and going through all the contents of the directory and calculating the size?

Tags: python, filesize, os.path

For example: What's the difference between using os.path.getsize(*directoryName*) like below:

```
>>>os.path.getsize('.')
>>>4096
```

and iterating over all the contents in that directory and calculating the size like below:

```
>>>totalSize = 0
>>>for filename in os.listdir('.'):
       totalSize += os.path.getsize('.\\' + filename)
>>>print(totalSize)
>>>8192
```

In the first method, I got 4096 bytes, and in the second method I got 8192 bytes. But the actual size of directory is 25.5 mb when I check with Windows Explorer.

Is my understanding of os.path.getsize() wrong? How do I get the size of a directory in Python?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404534/os-path-getsize-returns-incorrect-value.

Comment: @jarmod Oh sorry about the duplicate post. Thanks for pointing me to the answer!