# os.path.getsize() is not giving the true size of the file on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I am developing on OSX and My book states:

> Calling `os.path.getsize(path)` will return the size in bytes of the file in the path argument. Example:

```
os.path.getsize('C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe'`)
> 776192
```

It states that `os.path.getsize()` gives is the size in bytes but when I try to find the size of a folder on my desktop, it gives weird results.

There's a file on my desktop namely *Music*. I wrote this code in the shell:

```
os.path.getsize('/Users/apple/Desktop/Music')
> 510
```

This means that `Music`'s size must be 510 bytes but it has a size of 1.32GB!

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404534/os-path-getsize-returns-incorrect-value

Comment: Inasmuch as the question is stating that `Music` is a file, it's seriously misleading. Directories were files (as in, accessible via file-centric syscalls such as `read()`) in very early UNIX systems, but that hasn't been true for a long time, and certainly not in any version of MacOS that exists.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for clearing my misconception! 
Bdw, is there any command in Python which would give me the size of the directory itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're asking for the size of the directory itself, not the size of its contents. A directory in Unix (OSX) is considered to be a special file that contains meta data; Information that describes the directory on the file system. what `.getsize()` is telling you is that the meta data only occupies 510 bytes.

Notice the first example your book gives is asking for the size of a file called `calc.exe`, not a directory.

To get the total size of the contents of a directory, you need to recursively walk the entire hierarchy and call `getsize()` on every file. Here is a one line solution to do this:

```
sum([os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)])
```

Where `'.'` is the base path for the directory you're trying to get the size of.

Comment: Meta data is data about the directory, where it sits on disk, etc.

Comment: Is every folder situated on the desktop a directory?

Comment: "folder" is just another name for a directory. However, this discussion is going out of scope of the original question and this answer.

Comment: Could you please put the path that I am trying to use in your one-line-code as I am unable to use `f` properly?  The path is : `/Users/apple/desktop/Music`

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the size allocated by the directory only. Not the contents within it. `os.path.getsize()`
can get you the size of a file.

Note: A folder is actually considered to be "empty" if it contains subfolders only and no files.