# Finding the biggest folder within a directory tree

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that walks through a directory tree to find and print the folder with the largest size.

I have written the following code that works but was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it?

```
import os

def biggestFolder(directory):
    folderSize = []
    for folders, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        folderSize.append(os.path.getsize(folders))
        maxFolder = max(folderSize)
        if os.path.getsize(folders) == maxFolder:
            return folders



print(biggestFolder('/Users/ryanunderwood/Documents'))
```

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a folder with largest size, I don't see why you need `os.walk`, i.e. exhausting recursive search throughout directory. Your parent folders will obviously be larger than the folders inside. Also, `os.path.getsize` cannot be used for a folder, i.e. this is not counting the size recursively, instead only returning the size of the folder (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404634/5023889)).

To be neat, you can use `pathlib.Path` standard library.

```
from pathlib import Path
import operator

root = "/path/to/root/dir/"
p = Path(root)
folder_size_dict = {}

# Iterate through all folders
for subdir in p.iterdir():
    # Calculate recursively the size for each subdir
    subdir_size = sum(f.stat().st_size for f in subdir.glob('**/*') if f.is_file())
    folder_size_dict[subdir] = subdir_size

# Get folder (key) with largest size (value)
largest_folder = max(folder_size_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
print(f"Largest folder: {largest_folder} with size {folder_size_dict[largest_folder]}"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For linux/mac using OS commands, you can use:

```
import subprocess
dir = "/home/user/path/"
cmd = f"du -sk {dir}* | sort -n"
out =  subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
print(out.split("\n")[-1])
# 1547380 /home/user/public_html
```