# Recursive directory size includes symlinks twice

Tags: python, filesystems

I took code from a question on Stack Overflow that's supposed to measure a directory's size:

```
def dirSize(directory):
    totalSize = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            totalSize += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return totalSize
```

But if I have this directory:

```
ls -l
    -rw-r--r-- 1 lucas lucas 5120000 Oct 18 17:36 x
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 lucas lucas       1 Oct 18 17:34 y -> x
```

And I run that function on it, I get this:

```
10240000
```

It seems to count symlinks as the size of the file they link to, not 4KB as they actually are. How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating a directory size using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)

Comment: while the accepted answer there doesnt address his question the `stat` versions should

Comment: @vish that's the question I mentioned in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
totalSize += os.path.getsize(fp) if not os.path.islink(fp) else 4096
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass argument `followlinks=False` to `os.walk`. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) for more information.

Comment: this may not help since os.walk is not actually following the link `os.path.getsize` is +1 though since it might work (not in a position to test atm)

Comment: Isn't `followlinks=False` the default, in any case?

Comment: Didn't change anything - as DSM said, I think `followlinks` is off by default.