# Broken pipe using os.system for get the folder size

Tags: python, os.system, broken-pipe

I have a python script and I want to get the size of a folder (as fast as possible) like this:

```
 os.system("du -k folder |sort -nr| head -n 1 > size")
```

Although it seems that works, I get this error

```
sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe
sort: write error
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You say *"it seems that works"*, does that mean that you are getting the size back but also getting the error?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you run `du -k folder |sort -nr| head -n 1 > size` in a terminal? It seems like this shouldn't be a Python issue, so if you know for a fact that it is, you should add that to your question.

Comment: Yes, I get the size of the folder and also get the error. If I run it in a terminal I don't get the error.

Comment: I think [http://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error](http://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error) can solve your question. `head` shutdown the pipe in advance.

Comment: why are you using such a complicated call to get the size of the folder?

Comment: Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1392549/1084416): `sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f))`

Comment: `du -s folder > size` will do the same thing, if you want human readable use `sh`

Comment: @PeterWood the folder size is around 10 GBs and it is increasing each day..

Comment: Now using `os.system("du -sk folder > size")`

Comment: Note that `subprocess.call` is recommended over `os.system`; in your case `subprocess.check_output` with `shell=True`.

Answer (score 2):

Python sets the `SIGPIPE` signal to be ignored at startup. Therefore, when `sort` tries to write to the pipe when `head` has already finished and closed its stdin, `EPIPE` with the "broken pipe" message is raised. A workaround would be to reset `SIGPIPE` to its default action (see also [here](https://blog.nelhage.com/2010/02/a-very-subtle-bug/)).

```
# test case
python -c 'import os; os.system("LANG=C date | false")'  # date: stdout: Broken pipe
python -c 'import os, signal; signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL); os.system("LANG=C date | false")'
```

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce by making a `du` on a large directory. It happens because for a large directory, the sort process will do many writes to its standard input, and `head` will close its standard input (and exit) as soon as it can see it has one line.

Do you need to fix it? IMHO this is the way the commands `head` and `sort` work, and it does not mean that your value will be incorrect. So I would just redirect the standard error or sort to `/dev/null` to get rid of the message:

```
 os.system(" du -k folder |sort -nr 2>/dev/null| head -n 1")
```

But as already said by Padraic Cunningham, I think that this command is really complicated just to find the total size of a directory.

Answer (score 1):

As @mdurant said in a comment: The `subprocess` module is preffered over `os.system()`.  You can get the output of the external program directly into your program without an intermediate file, and also there is no extra shell process started between your program and the external program.

Example in an IPython session:

```
In [5]: subprocess.check_output(['du', '-sk', 'tmp'])
Out[5]: '101160\ttmp\n'

In [6]: subprocess.check_output(['du', '-sk', 'tmp']).split('\t', 1)
Out[6]: ['101160', 'tmp\n']

In [7]: subprocess.check_output(['du', '-sk', 'tmp']).split('\t', 1)[0]
Out[7]: '101160'

In [8]: int(subprocess.check_output(['du', '-sk', 'tmp']).split('\t', 1)[0])
Out[8]: 101160
```