# Passing ipython variable to bash command one line for loop

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I'm sorry for asking a duplicate as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35497069/10220019) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61606054/10220019) are very similar but with those answers I don't seem to be able to make my code work.

If have a jupyter notebook cell with:

```py
some_folder = "/some/path/to/files/*.gif"
!for name in {some_folder}; do echo $name; done
```

The output I get is just `{folder}`

If I do

```py
some_folder = "/some/path/to/files/*.gif"
!for name in "/some/path/to/files/*.gif"; do echo $name; done # <-- gives no newlines between file names
# or 
!for name in /some/path/to/files/*.gif; do echo $name; done # <-- places every filename on its own line
```

My gif files are printed to screen.

So my question why does it not use my python variable in the for loop?
Because the below, without a for loop, does work:

```py
some_folder = "/some/path/to/files/"
!echo {some_folder}
```

Follow up question: I actually want my variable to just be the folder and add the wildcard only in the for loop. So something like this:

```py
some_folder = "/some/path/to/files/"
!for name in {some_folder}*.gif; do echo $name; done
```

For context, later I actually want to rename the files in the for loop and not just print them. The files have an extra dot (not the one from the .gif extension) which I would like to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an alternative way to use shell bash in a Jupyter cell with cell magic, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19674648/8508004). It seems to allow what you are trying to do.

If you already ran in a normal cell `some_folder = r"/some/path/to/files/*.gif"` or `some_folder = "/some/path/to/files/*.gif"`, then you can try in a separate cell:

```bash
%%bash -s {some_folder}
for i in {1..5}; do echo $1; done
```

---

That said, what you seems to be trying to do with `some_folder = "/some/path/to/files/*.gif"` isn't going to work as such. If you try to pass `"/some/path/to/files/*.gif"` from Python to bash, it isn't going to work like passing `/some/path/to/files/*.gif` directly to bash. Bash isn't passing `"/some/path/to/files/*.gif"` directly to a command, it expands it and then passes it. There's not going to be an expansion passing from Python. And there's other peculiarities you'll come across. `Tar` you can pass a Python list of files directly using the bracket notation and it will handle that.

The solutions are to either do more on the Python side or more in the shell side. Python has it's own glob module, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). You can combine that with working with `os.system()`. Python has [fnamtch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) that is nice because you can use Unix-like file name matching. Plus there's [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) that allows moving/renaming, see `shutil.move()`. In Python `os.remove(temp_file_name)` can delete files. If you aren't working on a Windows machine there's the `sh` module that makes things nice. See [here](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32923739/8508004).