# os.path.getsize returns 0 although folder has files in it (Python 3.5)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program which auto-backups some folders under certain circumstances. 
I try to compare the size of two folders (source and dest), source has files in it, a flac file and a subfolder with a text file whereas dest is empty.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
import os.path
sls = os.path.getsize('D:/autobu/source/')
dls = os.path.getsize('D:/autobu/dest/')
print(sls)
print(dls)
if sls > dls:
    print('success')
else:
    print('fail')
```

And the output is this:

```
0
0
fail
```

What have I done wrong? Have I misunderstood how getsize functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating a directory size using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.getsize('D:/autobu/source/')` is used for getting size of a file 
you can folder size you can use `os.stat`

```
src_stat = os.stat('D:/autobu/source/')
sls = src_stat.st_size
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either. Yours as mine, only calculate a single file. For a whole folder I should probably use the code in Lukasz's link.