# Different size folders using python, terminal commands (ubuntu) and folder properties

Tags: python, ubuntu, size, directory

I want to get the size of a folder I'm working on and I've tried the following:

- right-click and check folder's properties (105.8MB)
- Commands directly in terminal:

  - du -hsc * (last line where total appears 105MB)
  - du -sch (last line
    where total appears 418MB)
- method from this answer:
  [Calculating a directory size using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)
  (418MB)

Why am I getting such different sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`du -sch *` will ignore hidden directories, so you'll usually get a smaller size with the asterisk than just running `du -sch`. That's really the only difference between all your examples above.

If you just need this value for displaying to a user, then choose which of those you'd like to display.

If you need an exact size, the `du` command is probably not what you want, since it displays **disk usage**, which will be different than file size if the disk block is greater than 1 byte.