# Getting File size from user inputed directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning through trying to make things and today I'm trying to get a program to give in bytes the total size of a directory, then display it's size.
So from what I have read online, I kind of understand what is going on up until the point of printing the data. Obviously I know it's wrong as it's not working.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you !

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os 

folder = raw_input("Folder Path : ")

folder_size = 0
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
  for file in files:
    filename = os.path.join(path, file)
    folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)

print ("Folder Size = ") + (folder_size)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating a directory size using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)

Comment: @Rahul I don't think it's a dupe, he's asking about the print statement, not about the logic of folder-size (perhaps it's a dupe of another thing regarding print statements, but not of this)

Comment: @OferSadan: Ok.

Answer (score 3):

The error is located in your `print` function.

Use `format` or `+` to concatenate strings and numbers. For instance, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

folder = raw_input("Folder Path : ")

folder_size = 0
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
  for file in files:
    filename = os.path.join(path, file)
    folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)

print ("Folder Size = {}".format(folder_size))
```