# Python: List one level of subdirectories sorted by last access date

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and I need to get a list of all first level subdirectories sorted inversely by last access date that I can crawl through.
The point is I'm writing a cleaning function that receives a variable containing the amount of megabytes to free. It should then walk through all first-level subdirectories and list them according to their last accessed date. Then the function should start deleting them until the needed amount of megabytes is relieved.

My code so far:

```
import os
def cleanSpace(megs,path="/var/lib/mpd/music/"):
    list = []
    for root, dir, file in os.walk(path):
        this_path = os.path.join(root, dir)
        stat = os.stat(this_path)
        this_atime = stat.st_atime
        this_size = round(stat.st_size/1048576)
        list.append([this_path,this_atime,this_size])
    sort(list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    total_freed = 0
    for folder in list:
        if total_freed < megs:
            #os.unlink(folder[0])
            print(folder[0])
            total_freed += folder[2]
        else:
            print("Total freed space:",total_freed)
            break
```

Comment: You should avoid overriding builtins by using them as variable names: `list`, `dir` and `file` are all special.

Comment: What results do you get with your code?

Comment: It seems that you expect `stat.st_size` to be the size of the subdirectory, which it isn't - it can only be used to get the size of a regular file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 errors I can see immediately:

```
for root, dir, file in os.walk(path):
    this_path = os.path.join(root, dir)
```

`dir` is a `list`, so you probably mean:

```
for root, dir, file in os.walk(path):
    for item in dir:
        this_path = os.path.join(root, item)
```

Note however that `os.walk` will 'drill down' into all sub-directories - if you want to just get the subdirectories at the top level, you probably mean:

```
for item in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(item):
```

There is no builtin method called `sort` - do you mean `sorted` (or is `sort` defined elsewhere?)

(Also as per my comment, `dir`, `list` and `file` are builtins you are overriding, so you should choose alternative variable names).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody!

One little problem. On my windows machine, os.path.getsize will report wrong numbers.

**UPDATE**: see below

Here is the final code:

```
import os
import datetime

def get_size(start_path = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size

def cleanSpace(megs,path="c:/Users/i/Downloads/"):
    list = []
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        fullitem=os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isdir(fullitem):
            this_path = fullitem
            stat = os.stat(fullitem)
            this_atime = stat.st_atime
            #print("Last access: ",this_atime)
            #print("Last access: ",datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(this_atime))
            this_size = get_size(fullitem)
            #size in MB
            this_size = round(this_size/1048576)
            list.append([fullitem,this_atime,this_size])
    list = sorted(list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)
    total_freed = 0
    for folder in list:
        if total_freed < megs:
            #os.unlink(folder[0])
            print(folder[0] + " - size: " + str(folder[2]))
            total_freed = total_freed + folder[2]
        else:
            print("Total freed space (MB):",total_freed)
            break
    if total_freed < megs:
        print("Not enough space freed")

cleanSpace(1100,)
```

For folder sizes I'm now using the function get_size() from [Calculating a directory's size using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directorys-size-using-python)