# Bytes returned by "disk_usage" from the shutil library doesn't match the directory file size

Tags: python, shutil, disk-access

I was reading the official documentation of **shutil** from the Python website, then I ran a **disk_usage** test, but it isn't returning what I was expecting, Inside that directory (folder) there's a single file of **669 kb**.

This is the code:

```
import os
import shutil

os.chdir(r"D:\python\topics\shutil\disk_usage")

directory = "test_folder"

total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(directory)

print(used)
```

Output:

```
177422868480 (which I suppose is the value in bytes)
```

Expected output:

```
669000 (since the file inside is 669 kb)
```

Why I'm not getting the expected output?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutil.disk_usage()` returns statistics for the entire disk (filesystem, volume), not just for the specific directory you pass in.

To compute disk space used by one directory and its subdirectories, see: [Calculating a directory's size using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directorys-size-using-python)

For a good introduction to some of the potential pitfalls, see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041228-00/?p=36863