# python3 recursively walk through a directory & find largest file size

Tags: python, os.walk

Let's say the program will be run by typing by command line:

python3  program.py  Downloads

Here is what I have so far.

```
import os
path = "Desktop"   //how do I change path to the random user inputed directory provided by command line?

fname = []
for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(path):
        for f in f_names:
                fname.append(os.path.join(root, f))

print("fname = %s" %fname)
```

Output:

```
fname = ['Desktop/Junk.odt']
```

I need to know how to find the largest file in the given directory and additionally print the filesize

Comment: This will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directorys-size-using-python

Comment: Thanks, but I think that sums the entire directory I just need the sum of the largest file in the directory

Comment: The answers are there, you just need to modify the code to do what you want.