# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison'

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

In My Python Script I was determining directory size in Azure Datalake storage Gen2.
And the code works fine until I check for a bigger directory.

```
import sys
from dbutils import FileInfo
from typing import List

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
root_path = "/mnt/datalake/.../"

def discover_size(path: str, verbose: bool = True):
  def loop_path(paths: List[FileInfo], accum_size: float):
    if not paths:
      return accum_size
    else:
      head, tail = paths[0], paths[1:]
      if head.size > 0:
        if verbose:
          accum_size += head.size / 1e6
        return loop_path(tail, accum_size)
      else:
        extended_tail = dbutils.fs.ls(head.path) + tail
        return loop_path(extended_tail, accum_size)

  return loop_path(dbutils.fs.ls(path), 0.0)

discover_size(root_path, verbose=True)
```

First see OOM(Out of Memory) Issue and added

`sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)`.

Now, Another error-

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

How to overcome this issue.

Comment: Show us your code. There's probably just an unbounded recursion bug in your code.

Comment: @AKX just a moment. I will add the code

Comment: @AKX Can you please check now.

Comment: depth of your new folder is just too big

Comment: @Mathix420 Ya as it has many sub folders and files. But what can be solution

Comment: not sure but maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392549/9799292 (2019 update)

Comment: @Mathix420 This isn't an OS path, it's a Databricks file system.

Comment: maybe just a queue like system instead of calling `loop_path()` store a path in a list and while there is a path in this list append his size to a variable

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [`dbutils.fs.ls()`](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutilsfsls-command) are far from perfect and I don't have a DataBricks environment at hand, but something like this should probably work better without using real recursion, but a list of paths left to visit.

```
import dbutils


def discover_size(path: str) -> int:
    total_size = 0
    visited = set()
    to_visit = [path]
    while to_visit:
        path = to_visit.pop(0)
        if path in visited:
            print("Already visited %s..." % path)
            continue
        visited.add(path)
        print(
            f"Visiting %s, size %s so far..." % (path, total_size),
        )
        for info in dbutils.fs.ls(path):
            total_size += info.size
            if info.isDir():
                to_visit.add(info.path)
    return total_size


discover_size("/mnt/datalake/.../", verbose=True)
```

Comment: This shows syntax error with print(f"Already visited {path}...") with "f" if I nullify this line, I get no outcome.

Comment: That syntax error means you're using an older version of Python. Anyway, updated the code for compatibility