# Efficient drive scan using recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, directory, cython, python-multiprocessing

**Original Question:**

I am trying to recursively scan directories in order to get the occupied size of a disk and details for each file and folder using the code below. The code below works perfectly fine but I need some advice on improving its efficiency, in order to scan drives that have 200 GB or more in occupied space/data. The testing results for a disk with 5.49 GB(244,169 files and 34,253 folders) occupied space are as follow:

1. If the code is run without the list append operation it takes roughly 8 mins to scan the disk which is not highly efficient
2. It gets even worse if I include the list append statement, then it takes roughly 25 mins --> Bottleneck

```
import os
import sys
import logging
from os.path import *

def scanSlot(path):
    """Return total size of files in given path and subdirs."""
    global dir_list
    global path_list
    try:
        dir_list = os.scandir(path)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(">>> Access Denied for " + path)
        dir_list = {}

    tot_size = 0 
    for file in dir_list:
        file_stat = file.stat()
        time_stat = os.stat(file.path)

            # If the given file object is a directory recursively call the function again
            if file.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):

                #Recursive Call
                bytes = scanSlot(file.path)

                #Calculating Size
                tot_size += bytes

                # logging.info('Dirname:'+str(file)+' Path'+str(file.path) +' Size'+str(bytes))
         
                # List Append
                path_list.append((file.name,file.path,file_stat.st_mode,file_stat.st_ino,file_stat.st_dev,file_stat.st_nlink,file_stat.st_uid,file_stat.st_gid,tot_size,
                                       datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stat.st_atime),datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stat.st_mtime),datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stat.st_ctime),"dir"))

            # If the given file object is a file then retrieve all the details
            if file.is_file(follow_symlinks=False):
               
                # logging.info('Filename:'+str(file)+ ' Path'+str(file.path) +' Size'+str(time_stat))
    
                tot_size += file.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size

                # List Append
                path_list.append((file.name,file.path,file_stat.st_mode,file_stat.st_ino,file_stat.st_dev,file_stat.st_nlink,file_stat.st_uid,file_stat.st_gid,file_stat.st_size,
                                      datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stat.st_atime),datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stat.st_mtime),datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stat.st_ctime),"file"))
    return tot_size
```

Function call for above code:

```
server_size = scanSlot('D:\\New folder')
```

I have tried to optimize the code using the following methods:

1. Python library [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), this doesn't work since numba does not have an implementation for the os library being used.
2. Trying to convert code to [Cython](https://cython.org/) but not really sure if that will help

The list append operation cannot be overlooked as the details in that path_list are required for further analysis.

**Updates:**

As per the suggestion from [@triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) and with help of the implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directorys-size-using-python) I have implemented the directory scan using os.walk() and clearly it's way faster(19.6GB with 2,75,559 files 38,592 folder scanned in 20mins while doing an I/O to a log file for each file directory). The code is as follows:

*FYI: STILL TESTING THIS*

```
def scanSlot(path):
    total_size = 0
    global path_list
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
                
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            # skip if it is symbolic link
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                # logging.info('Filename:'+str(fp)+'Size:'+str(os.path.getsize(fp)))
                file_stat = os.stat(fp)
                path_list.append((f,fp,file_stat.st_mode,file_stat.st_ino,file_stat.st_dev,file_stat.st_nlink,file_stat.st_uid,file_stat.st_gid,os.path.getsize(fp),
                                       datetime.fromtimestamp(file_stat.st_atime),datetime.fromtimestamp(file_stat.st_mtime),datetime.fromtimestamp(file_stat.st_ctime),"file"))
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)


    return total_size

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info('>>> Start:' + str(datetime.now().time()))

    # So basically run os.walk() for a drive and then do so for all directories present in it

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('F:\\'):

        for f in dirnames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            dir_size = scanSlot(fp)
            file_stat = os.stat(fp)
            logging.info('Dirname:'+str(fp)+'Size:'+str(dir_size))
            path_list.append((f,fp,file_stat.st_mode,file_stat.st_ino,file_stat.st_dev,file_stat.st_nlink,file_stat.st_uid,dir_size,
                                       datetime.fromtimestamp(file_stat.st_atime),datetime.fromtimestamp(file_stat.st_mtime),datetime.fromtimestamp(file_stat.st_ctime),"dir"))
           
           
    logging.info('>>> End:' + str(datetime.now().time()))
```

**Further Questions:**

- How to make this even more efficient/faster, initially I had thought of multiprocessing as in parallelly running the scan for 3 drives under 3 different processes.

Refrences:

- [os.scandir()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)
- [is_file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_file)
- [is_dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_dir)
- [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)
- [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20walk#os.walk)
- [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

The explanation for ***follow_symlinks*** can also be found in the reference links above.

Comment: Why aren't you using `os.walk()`?

Comment: Dont know much about how that worrks but i'll try that out