# In between 2 paths how do i compare list of directories sizes(which are with same name) and report using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am able to get only common files through this code i want size comparison of both path directories.

```
import filecmp
result=filecmp.dircmp(path1,path2)
print result.report()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this question here:
[Calculating a directory's size using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directorys-size-using-python)
There are a lot of ways of doing this, and on this question they list several "tools" that may fit your problem

Comment: But don't we have any direct function which compare size of python directories like filecmp.dircmp do by providing all common list directories?

Comment: I don't believe so. You can also have a look at this ready funcion: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/get-directory-size-in-bytes-using-python