# How to calculate free space of a directory using Python

Tags: python, diskspace

How can I use python to monitor growth or capacity of a folder that is to determine the used and free space so that by the end of the day I can keep track how much my project is consuming space and create a graphical report for the same.

I tried to use os.statvfs function but it shows module 'os' has no attribute 'statvfs'
I have got the idea to calculate used but if anyone can help with free space code would mean a lot. Thanks.

Comment: did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392549/3297680

Comment: The link answers only the used space half of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import shutil

path = '/' # write any path here
total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(path)

print("Total: %d GiB" % (total // (2**30)))
print("Used: %d GiB" % (used // (2**30)))
print("Free: %d GiB" % (free // (2**30)))
```