# What is the fastest way to get a folder size in python on Windows pc

Tags: python-3.x, windows, directory, subprocess, size

I'd like to know what's the fastest way to get a folder/directory size (in bytes as I'll format them to another size later) in python on a Windows OS pc. The current python version I am using is 3.8. I have tried the following function in python to obtain it:

```
def get_dir_size(directory):
    total = 0
    try:
        for entry in os.scandir(directory):
            if entry.is_file():
                total += os.path.getsize(entry.path)
            elif entry.is_dir():
                total += get_directory_size(entry.path)
    except NotADirectoryError:
        return os.path.getsize(directory)

    return total
```

However, I realised that the above code takes too long to run as I have quite a few folders to calculate its size, and a large folder with many degrees of subfolders will take up a lot of time to calculate the overall size.

Instead, I was attempting various approaches and have hit a roadblock for this current one. In this approach, I tried to use subprocess.run to run a powershell command and obtain the size. Here is the code I wrote to do so:

```
folder_path = C:\Users\username\Downloads\test_folder # Suppose this path is a legitimate path
command = fr"Get-ChildItem -Path {folder_path} -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | Select-Object Sum, Count"
proc = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout)
```

The final output I get when I print `proc.stdout` is empty, and an error is printed saying that the command I gave is `not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

I would appreciate it if I can get some advice on how to make this work, or if possible, provide suggestions on how to get the folder size in a shorter time possible. The current workable approach I have takes too many hours, and in between the network might get cut.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this answering ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directorys-size-using-python

Comment: @DamienCastaignede Thanks for the help. The method listed in the thread is similar to what I've already implemented, so I'll need help on another suggestion.

Comment: oh sorry, then I guess I would advise to not do it in Python ? Maybe try to wrap a c function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently encountered the same problem as you did. While there may be other optimal solutions, here's how I dealt with it. But before, I want to mention that The 'subprocess' package [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor#p:%7E:text=On%20Windows%20with%20shell%3DTrue%2C%20the%20COMSPEC%20environment%20variable%20specifies%20the%20default%20shell.) states that:

> On Windows with `shell=True`, the "***COMSPEC environment variable"*** specifies the default shell.

Typically, this variable is set to `cmd.exe` by default, which means that any command passed to `subprocess.run()` will be executed in the command prompt. That is why, when you tried to run the powershell cmdlet `Get-ChildItem`, cmd was unable to recognize it, which led to that error message.

So to execute the PowerShell command you have in cmd, call the PowerShell process using the `-Command` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command) as illustrated below:

```
command = f"powershell -command \"(Get-ChildItem -Force -Path '{folder_path}' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | measure -Property Length -Sum).sum\""
```

Note the additional `-Force` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-force), which allows the cmdlet to get items that are not normally accessible by the user (i.e. that needs admin privileges), such as hidden or system files.

However, after I ran a speed test, I found that this method is slower compared to the `os.walk()` method when dealing with ***folders that contain a relatively small number of files***. This could potentially be attributed to the time required for the PowerShell interface to load in the background before executing the command, (although I am uncertain about this). The speed test was performed on the following methods:

1. [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3), (powershell)
2. [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), (python)
3. [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir), (a built-in cmd command)

Here are the results of my benchmarking:

| Folder Size | **childitem_method** | **walk_method** | **dir_method** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Gb (2 items) | 1.6201 sec | ***0.0013 sec*** | 0.1968 sec |
| 6 Gb (60 items) | 1.6853 sec | ***0.0179 sec*** | 0.2020 sec |
| 3 Gb (1000 items) | 1.9482 sec | 0.2969 sec | ***0.2832 sec*** |
| 10 Gb (10000 items) | 4.5680 sec | 2.8583 sec | ***2.0390 sec*** |
| 27 Gb (15000 items) | 6.1768 sec | 4.7842 sec | ***2.8775 sec*** |
| 77 Gb (670000 items) | 6 min : 30 sec | 8 min : 17 sec | ***3 min : 37 sec*** |

Here is the implementation of the three methods I used:

```
import os
import subprocess
import re
import timeit

def childitem_method(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        command = f"powershell -command \"(Get-ChildItem -Force -Path '{path}' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | measure -Property Length -Sum).sum\""
        output = (
            subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
            .decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
            .strip()
        )
        return int(output) if output.isnumeric() else None

def walk_method(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        return sum(
            sum(
                os.path.getsize(os.path.join(walk_result[0], element))
                for element in walk_result[2]
            )
            for walk_result in os.walk(path)
        )

def dir_method(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        command = f'chcp 65001 > nul && dir "{path}" /s /a /-C'
        output = (
            subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
            .decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
            .strip()
            .rsplit("\n", 2)[1]
        )
        output = re.findall(r"\d+", output)[-1]
        return int(output) if output.isnumeric() else None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path, repetitions = r"C:\ ".strip(), 100
    print("childitem_method:",
        timeit.timeit(lambda: childitem_method(folder_path), number=repetitions)/repetitions)
    print("walk_method:     ",
        timeit.timeit(lambda: walk_method(folder_path), number=repetitions)/repetitions)
    print("dir_method:      ",
        timeit.timeit(lambda: dir_method(folder_path), number=repetitions)/repetitions)
```