# I am trying to get the size of a file with os.path.getsize but it prints out the size as bytes and I want to print it out in MB, any solutions?

Tags: python, os.path

I am trying to get the size of a file with os.path.getsize but it prints out the size as bytes and I want to print it out in MB, any solutions?
The code:

```
import os
from os import system
os = os.path.getsize("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\ambrosial.exe")
print(str(os))
```

Comment: Yes.  Divide by 1024*1024. Or divide by `1 << 20`.  That aside, did you notice you’ve overwritten the `os` import as a variable?  That aside, you’ve already imported `os`, so the second import is not needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to convert file sizes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194057/better-way-to-convert-file-sizes-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Basically, you get the size of your file, then you convert the size of the file from bytes to megabytes by dividing by (1024 * 1024).

```
import os 
byte_size = os.path.getsize("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\ambrosial.exe")
mb_size = byte_size / (1024 * 1024)
print(mb_size)
```