# Python-Gitlab print project name, owner, size, owner_group

Tags: python, gitlab

Could you help to print what I need with python-gitlab request? I need to print:

Project-Name
Owner
Group Owner
Size

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gitlab
import os
import sys

GITLAB_SERVER = os.environ.get('GL_SERVER', 'https://gitlab.instance.com')
# Token loaded in env var
GITLAB_TOKEN = os.environ.get('GL_TOKEN')

if not GITLAB_TOKEN:
    print("Please set the GL_TOKEN env variable.")
    sys.exit(1)

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(GITLAB_SERVER, private_token=GITLAB_TOKEN)

# Main
groups = gl.groups.list(get_all=True,statistics=True)
projects = gl.projects.list(get_all=True,statistics=True)

# Print Project Name, Group, Owner, Size
```

Another request:
There are more than 3000 projects so do you know how to set up a progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can retrieve the data from the API + using `tqdm` as status bar:

```py
import gitlab
from tqdm import tqdm

GITLAB_SERVER = <your server url>
GITLAB_TOKEN = <your token>

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(GITLAB_SERVER, private_token=GITLAB_TOKEN)

# note the `iterator=` parameter:
projects = gl.projects.list(iterator=True, statistics=True)

data = []
for p in tqdm(projects, total=projects.total):
    data.append(
        {
            "name": p.name,
            "owner": p.owner["username"],
            "size": p.statistics["repository_size"],
        }
    )

print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm trying to improve the script to suit my needs. Do you know how to convert size to MB?

Comment: @Vorbisset Maybe you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/14822210/10035985 ?