# How to get the size of tar.gz in (MB) file in python

Tags: python, linux, file-io

I am doing backups in python script but i need to get the size of tar.gz file created in MB

How can i get the size in MB of that file

Comment: Do you want the size of the uncompressed file that's inside the archive or do you just want the size of the archive itself?

Comment: just the size of archive itself

Comment: See also: [Reusable library to get human readable version of file size?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1094933/562769)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you want to the compressed or uncompressed size of the file, but in the former case, it's easy with the `os.path.getsize` function [from the os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.getsize('flickrapi-1.2.tar.gz')
35382L
```

To get the answer in megabytes you can shift the answer right by 20, e.g.

```
os.path.getsize('large.tar.gz') >> 20
```

Although that operation will be done in integers - if you want to preserve fractions of a megabyte, divide by `(1024*1024.0)` instead.  (Note the `.0` so that the divisor will be a float.)

**Update:** In the comments below, [Johnsyweb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78845/johnsyweb) points out a useful recipe for more generally [producing human readable representations of file sizes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577081-humanized-representation-of-a-number-of-bytes/).

Comment: it means i have to divide by 1024*1024 to make it in MB

Comment: See also this recipe [to get a human-readable representation of a number of bytes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577081-humanized-representation-of-a-number-of-bytes/).

Comment: @Johnsyweb: thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the answer to add that link.

Answer (score 7):

To get file size in MB, I created this function:

```py
import os

def get_size(path):
        size = os.path.getsize(path)
        if size < 1024:
            return f"{size} bytes"
        elif size < pow(1024,2):
            return f"{round(size/1024, 2)} KB"
        elif size < pow(1024,3):
            return f"{round(size/(pow(1024,2)), 2)} MB"
        elif size < pow(1024,4):
            return f"{round(size/(pow(1024,3)), 2)} GB"
```

```py
>>> get_size("k.tar.gz")
1.4MB
```

Comment: Elegant codes <3

Comment: Nice piece of code. Under Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) to find the same value that is shown in file explorer you have to use `1000` instead of `1024`  because Linux in that case shows kb, Mb, or Gb as explained https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/13815

Answer (score 3):

Use the `os.stat()` function to get a stat structure. The `st_size` attribute of that is the size of the file in bytes.

Comment: (+1) Seems much better than my idea (I initially thought the OP wants to assess what's in the tar file too).

Answer (score 0):

According to Python [on-line docs](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarInfo), you should look at the `size` attributes of a `TarInfo` object.

Comment: @Mahakaal It works with `*.tar` file too (just read it with the `r` flag and not `r:gz` passed to `tarfile.open`). However, it gives the size of each element included in the tar file (easy to sum up, though), so maybe one of the alternative answer might better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to get it directly without any hazel

```
os.path.getsize('filename.tar') >> 20
print str(filename.tgz) + " MB"
```