# What caused different result in size convertion (hurry.filesize vs Fred Cirera) in Python?

Tags: python

I tried to convert file size from bytes to a human readable format. There's the [hurry.filesize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.filesize/) package, and another implementaion by Fred Cirera [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094841/reusable-library-to-get-human-readable-version-of-file-size):

Using hurry.filesize:

```
size(1024 ** 3.4)
Out[69]: '15G'
```

Using Fred Cirera:

```
sizeof_fmt(1024 ** 3.4)
Out[68]: '16.0GiB'
```

I am confused, so I try to calculate

```
1024 ** 0.4
Out[71]: 16.000000000000004
```

Why they got different result?

Comment: `1024 ** 3.4` is `17179869183.999989`, divided by `1073741824` (one GB) is `15.99999999999999`. It's *almost* 16 GB but not quite, which is why the two may differ (one truncates and the other rounds, or something like that).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, you're right. From the `hurry.filesize` source code:     `amount = int(bytes/factor)` - it is truncated. (Personally, I think it should not). Thank you!