# Convert number with units in python to NON human readable format

Tags: python, human-readable

What would be the best way to convert a numerical column containing float AND unit as in :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["211.301 MB","435.5 GB","345.234 Bytes"])
```

expected output in Bytes for example:

```
211.301*1024*1024 = 221565157.376
```

Many questions like this one :
[Reusable library to get human readable version of file size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094841/reusable-library-to-get-human-readable-version-of-file-size)

are showing ways of doing the opposite : convert number to human readable. How to convert human readable to float ?

Is there a more efficient way than splitting :

```
spl = pd.DataFrame(dataf['Total_Image_File_Size'].str.split(' ',expand=True))
```

and then parsing the units column with multiples if's ?

Thanx

Comment: Just create a dictionary, mapping letters to exponents? `{'K': 2**10, 'M': 2**20, ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this one should work: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanfriendly

```
>>> import humanfriendly
>>> user_input = raw_input("Enter a readable file size: ")
Enter a readable file size: 16G
>>> num_bytes = humanfriendly.parse_size(user_input)
>>> print num_bytes
17179869184
>>> print "You entered:", humanfriendly.format_size(num_bytes)
You entered: 16 GB
```

Comment: Wow, I missed this one. This is great !

Answer (score 1):

You could create function to convert text to value and use `apply`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["211.301 MB","435.5 GB","345.234 Bytes"])


def convert(text):

    parts = text.split(' ')

    value = float(parts[0])

    if parts[1] == 'KB':
        value *= 1024
    elif parts[1] == 'MB':
        value *= 1024 * 1024
    elif parts[1] == 'GB':
        value *= 1024 * 1024

    return value



df['value'] = df[0].apply(convert)


           0         value  
0     211.301 MB  2.215652e+08  
1       435.5 GB  4.566548e+08  
2  345.234 Bytes  3.452340e+02
```

**EDIT:** you could use `humanfriendly` in this function instead of `if/elif`

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea.

```
>>> for size in "211.301 MB", "435.5 GB", "345.234 Bytes":
        number, unit = size.split()
        print float(number) * 1024**'BKMGT'.index(unit[0])

221565157.376
4.67614564352e+11
345.234
```