# Multiple bit manipulation in python

Tags: python, string, bit

I have a variable containing a value in bit, ex 10000000 representing 10mb. I'd like to write a function that from a value in bit, return a string with the right unit and correctly converted.

Example if I use 52200000, it returns 52.2mb.

I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help, thank you

Comment: 10000000 bytes are not 10 mb.

Comment: Can you post five or ten other example inputs and outputs?

Comment: This formats bytes to human readable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094841/reusable-library-to-get-human-readable-version-of-file-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def humanize(n):
   base=1000.0   # replace with 1024 if you want kib Mib etc
   letters=['','k','M','G','T','P','E','Z','Y'] 
   f=float(n)
   for x in letters:
       if f < base: break
       f /= base
   return '{:.3}{}b'.format(f,x) # change {}b to {}ib if working with kib etc.
```

These days Mb normally refers to a decimal million bytes and Mib normally refers to 1024*1024 of them. This code is trivial to switch.

Comment: Mb refers to Million *Bits*, MB is Million *Bytes*

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def bytesto(bytes, to, bsize=1000):
>     a = {'k' : 1, 'm': 2, 'g' : 3, 't' : 4, 'p' : 5, 'e' : 6 }
>     r = float(bytes)
>     for i in range(a[to]):
>         r = r / bsize
>     return(r)
> ```
>
> you can use above function to convert bytes to kb,mb,gb,tb

- Convert bytes to KB `print(bytesto(314575262000000, 'k')) # 314575262000.0 KB`
- Convert bytes to MB `print(bytesto(314575262000000, 'm')) # 314575262.0 MB`
- Convert bytes to TB `print(bytesto(314575262000000, 't')) # 314.575262 TB`

Comment: You're confusing MB (=1000B) and MiB (=1024B) - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: @mata Got IT the difference  between MIB and MB. Thanks