# How to get bandwidth from eth0 use python script?

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, bandwidth

Python in ubuntu ifconfig  : How to get bandwidth value from device eth0 use os modules ifconfig in python script, like this:

```
$python script.py eth0
UP: 5 KB/sec
DOWN: 30.5 KB/sec
```

where output script can change every second time and value bandwidth use Kb/s
?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) to get information about network interfaces like this:

```
psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
```

This will return something like the following

```
{'awdl0': snetio(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'bridge0': snetio(bytes_sent=342L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=1L, packets_recv=0L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'en0': snetio(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'en1': snetio(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'en4': snetio(bytes_sent=68008896L, bytes_recv=1972984495L, packets_sent=776722L, packets_recv=1487084L, errin=0L, errout=10L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'lo0': snetio(bytes_sent=87119711L, bytes_recv=87119711L, packets_sent=54606L, packets_recv=54606L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0)}
```

You can measure the difference on sent/received bytes once every second and print the up/down speeds. If you want the speeds to be human readable take a look at how you at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094841/reusable-library-to-get-human-readable-version-of-file-size).

Comment: Is use python script??