# Change column values in a Pandas Dataframe to show numbers as Milions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a Pandas DataFrame

```
   Symbol  Name  ...  % Change      Volume
9     XXX  YYY   ...     -3.62  58792000.0
11    XXX  YYY   ...      0.18  58587000.0
```

I would like to change the values in 'Volume' to have this result

```
   Symbol  Name  ...  % Change      Volume
9     XXX  YYY   ...     -3.62  58.792M
11    XXX  YYY   ...      0.18  58.587M
```

Comment: You may want to check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094841/get-human-readable-version-of-file-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get to your desired result literally step by step, by adding a '$' sign, dividing the number by `1000000`, and adding the `MM` suffix:

```
df['Volume'] = '$' + (df['Volume'].astype(float)/1000000).astype(str) + 'MM'

print(df)

  Symbol Name  % Change     Volume
0    XXX  YYY    -3.620  $58.792MM
1    XXX  YYY     0.180  $58.587MM
```

Note that the resulting 'Volume' `dtype` will be `object`:

```
df.dtypes

Symbol       object
Name         object
% Change    float64
Volume       object
dtype: object
```

Happy to see if there's a more pythonic way by others.

Comment: I got this error
`<stdin>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`

Comment: The code works, you just received a warning. Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas for further information.

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple like this -

```
(df.Volume/1000000).round(3).astype(str)+'M'
```

Just divide the column by a million, round it to 3 significant digits, convert to str, and then add an 'M' at the end.