# transform file, directories and their children into an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are there any methods or plugins that allow me to transform a directory with files and other directories inside (including if I hear something inside them) into an object in python?

I want to pass a list with all the files and directories of a specific path, with name, size and its complete path, is there any simple way to do it? What would be the best way to resolve this?

exemple:

```
/app
 -file1
 -file2
 -dir1
  -dir2
   -file3
  -file4
```

to:

```
    obj=[
      {name=file1, size= 10kb, path='/app/file1'},
      ...,
      {name=dir1, size= 100kb, path='/app/dir1', child={name=file4, size= 10kb, path='/app/file4'} ,...}  
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two python functions that are useful for traversing files in a directory.

[`os.walk()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) will recursively walk all files and directories in a given file, and give you a lot of control about the traversal.

[`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) is a much simpler function that just returns a list of all the file names in a directory.

I used `os.listdir` in a recursive function to create the structure you described:

```py
import os

def list_files(directory):
    files = []
    for f in os.listdir(directory):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, f)
        file = {
            "name": f,
            "size": os.path.getsize(file_path),
            "path": file_path,
        }
        if os.path.isdir(file_path):
            file["children"] = list_files(file_path)
        files.append(file)
    return files

print( list_files("my/directory") )
```

Comment: I think ```os.path.getsize(file_path)``` return the number of bytes of the file.

Comment: If you want the size as a human-readable string, [here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094841/get-human-readable-version-of-file-size) discussing how to do that

Comment: I just mention it. np.