# The sizes of saved vector outputs (PDF, EPS) are too large when using mplcairo as the Matplotlib backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, cairo

As the title says, I'm using [mplcairo](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplcairo) as the Matploblit backend. However, the saved files are too large compared to those using the default Matplotlib backend. I want to reduce the file sizes.

This question is also posted on GitHub: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplcairo/issues/37

### Version Information

```sh
>>> import mplcairo
>>> mplcairo.get_versions()
{'python': '3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51) \n[GCC 7.5.0]', 'mplcairo': '0.4', 'matplotlib': '3.5.1', 'cairo': '1.16.0', 'freetype': '2.10.1', 'pybind11': '2.6.2', 'raqm': None, 'hb': None}
```

### Problem Specification

#### `mplcairo` Backend

Code:

```sh
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
print("matplotlib.__version__:", matplotlib.__version__)
print('Default backend:', matplotlib.get_backend())
matplotlib.use("module://mplcairo.base")
# matplotlib.use("cairo")
print('Backend is now:', matplotlib.get_backend())
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42


def format_size(num, suffix="B"):
    """Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094933
    """
    for unit in ["", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z"]:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            return f"{num:3.1f}{unit}{suffix}"
        num /= 1024.0
    return f"{num:.1f}Y{suffix}"


# Plot and save figures
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), dpi=300)
for i in range(5):
    ax.plot(range(100000), np.random.rand(100000), linewidth=2.0)
fig.savefig('./mplcairo_file_size_test.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
fig.savefig('./mplcairo_file_size_test.eps', format='eps', bbox_inches='tight')
fig.savefig('./mplcairo_file_size_test.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
print("Figures saved!")


# Display the sizes
pathlist = [ Path("./mplcairo_file_size_test.pdf"), Path("./mplcairo_file_size_test.eps"), Path("./mplcairo_file_size_test.png") ]
for path in sorted(pathlist):
    print("{:s}: {:s}".format(path.name, format_size(path.stat().st_size)))
```

Output:

```sh
matplotlib.__version__: 3.5.1
Default backend: module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline
Backend is now: module://mplcairo.base
Figures saved!
mplcairo_file_size_test.eps: 8.4MB
mplcairo_file_size_test.pdf: 8.4MB
mplcairo_file_size_test.png: 63.2KB
```

#### Default Backend

Code is the same as the `mplcairo` code except that the `matplotlib.use` line is commented out so that the default backend is used.

Output:

```sh
matplotlib.__version__: 3.5.1
Default backend: module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline
Backend is now: module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline
Figures saved!
mplcairo_file_size_test.eps: 1.2MB
mplcairo_file_size_test.pdf: 535.4KB
mplcairo_file_size_test.png: 76.8KB
```

#### Observation

The vector files (PDF, EPS) produced by `mplcairo` are much larger than those produced by the default backend (**8.4MB v.s. 1.2MB**). This issue is worse when there are more lines (`Artist`s) in the figure. The difference in the file size is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has fixed the library (see [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplcairo/issues/37)). This question should be accordingly closed.